# Dividing main update function based on sub-messages

Tags: architecture, message, elm, reducers

I am trying to separate my top level messages to sub messages and hence i did:

```elm
type GeneratorMsg
    = BoidsGenerated (List Boid)
    | ColoursGenerated (List Color)


type Msg
    = Tick Time
    | UpdateWorld Window.Size
    | GeneratorMsg
```

However, in my main update function when I use the *BoidsGenerated* message Elm thinks that it is of type *GeneratorMsg* which is correct. In the same time though - in my mind -, it is of type *Msg*.

Is there a way to be able to handle *Msg* and *GeneratorMsg* interchangeably? Basically, i want to split my update function to smaller functions but I want everything that has to do with generated stuff to be handled by 1 separate function. Then that function will have cases for *BoidsGenerated* and *ColoursGenerated* msgs. --- thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a collision of names. You have a type called `GeneratorMsg` as well as a constructor called `GeneratorMsg` of a different type (`Msg`).

The way you have defined the `GeneratorMsg` constructor of `Msg`, it is parameterless and contains no payload of information. You need to define a parameter to carry the `GeneratorMsg` value:

```elm
type Msg
    = Tick Time
    | UpdateWorld Window.Size
    | GeneratorMsg GeneratorMsg
```

You could then handle the updates in a separate function but you'll have to `Cmd.map` to wrap up the `GeneratorMsg` into a `Msg` value:

```elm
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        GeneratorMsg gmsg ->
            let
                ( gmodel, newMsg ) =
                    updateGenerator gmsg model
            in
                (gmodel, Cmd.map GeneratorMsg newMsg)

        _ ->
            ...


updateGenerator : GeneratorMsg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd GeneratorMsg )
updateGenerator gmsg model =
    case gmsg of
        BoidsGenerated boids ->
            ...

        ColoursGenerated colours ->
            ...
```